# CheckboxSelectMultiple doesn't pre-check boxes with inital value set to queryset

Tags: python, django, forms

I am working on a kid's email program that will populate checkboxes with the appropriate mail recipients after 'reply all' is clicked.  When I create the template for the reply email, I need to generate the choices dynamically as well as as the pre-checked boxes.  Everything works except that the boxes don't get checked. I've read a lot of related questions here but none populating directly from a queryset. I don't understand how/where to set "initial".  To be sure that my filter is not causing the problem, I have set both the queryset and the initial to the same value, expecting all of the boxes to be checked, and none are.  Thanks for any help.

```
forms.py:
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None, 
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

email_views.py:
def email_compose_show(request, reply_type, email_id):
    if reply_type == 'reply-all':
        msg = Mail.objects.get(id=email_id)
    qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(id__in=get_users(request.user.id)).exclude(id=request.user.id)
    form = EmailForm(initial={'message': msg.message, 'subject': msg.subject})

    recipients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label="Recipients",
        widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=qs,
        initial=qs
    )
    form.fields['recipients'] = recipients

template:
{% for x,y in form.fields.recipients.choices %}
    <label for="id_recipients_{{forloop.counter0}}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="recipients" 
    id="id_recipients_{{forloop.counter0}}" value="{{ x }}"> {{ y }} 
</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because you've specifically avoided using the helpers Django gives you to populate the field. There's literally nothing in the template that would tell the browser to show any of the checkboxes as selected.

Instead of iterating through the recipients choices manually, you should let Django do it; replace all that template code with just

```
{{ form.recipients }}
```

Note, you really shouldn't be modifying the field itself in the view; it's best to pass initial as a parameter to the form instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - this worked right away.  I was hoping however to get a side-by-side layout for the checkboxes.  Somehow I thought "choices" would include the checked status but I misunderstood it.  There must be a "checked" attribute I can catch in an {% if %} within the <input> tags.  Any ideas?

Comment: Realized I can solve this by testing the user's presence in a receipients list passed into the context rather than testing on this checked attribute.  But still curious for the knowledge.